# The Google Time Zone API always returns Error status

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, timezone

I am using  Google Time Zone API  to retrieve time zone, my code is

```
$lat = round($location['lat'], 2);
$lng = round($location['lng'], 2);

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/jsonlocation=".$lat.",".$lng."&amp;timestamp=1419283200&sensor=false";
$url = str_replace(' ','',$url);
$json_timezone = file_get_contents($url);
echo $url;
echo '<pre>';print_r($json_timezone);
```

And the output is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.29,-76.64&timestamp=1419283200&sensor=false

{
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

When I run the above url, I get the correct output

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : -18000,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/New_York",
   "timeZoneName" : "Eastern Standard Time"
}
```

Any Idea how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$url` is invalid. Try this:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=".$lat.",".$lng."&timestamp=1419283200&sensor=false";
```